# How do I render a higher quality image via CustomRenderer in iOS with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

This is fairly straight forward, but I have some custom ShellRenderers for my App in Xamarin Forms, and I'm having issues with the scaling of images.  In particular, Android looks fantastic with the more pixel-dense image (800x200).  It looks great on every screen.

The renderer just ensures that the top of the screen is made of the "theme" color, and is presented in the center of the it.  It's that simple/straight-forward.

On iOS, it looks awful and blurred.  I'm not sure if there's something I need to set or update (or maybe a different graphics stack?) to make it render with higher pixel density...  See my attached renderer:

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    #region Methods

    protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
    {
        var renderer = base.CreateShellSectionRenderer(shellSection);

        if (renderer != null)
        {
            var navigationBar = (renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar;

            if (navigationBar != null)
            {
                navigationBar.BarTintColor = Colors.LightColor.ToUIColor(); //static colors
                navigationBar.TintColor = Colors.LightColor.ToUIColor();

                using (var logo = UIImage.FromResource(typeof(Images).Assembly, "Path.To.Logo.png"))
                {
                    var statusFrame = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame;
                    var navigationFrame = navigationBar.Frame;

                    var width = Math.Max(navigationFrame.Width, statusFrame.Width);
                    var fullArea = new CGRect(0, 0, width, navigationFrame.Height + statusFrame.Height);

                    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(fullArea.Size);

                    var backgroundColor = Colors.PrimaryColor.ToUIColor();
                    backgroundColor.SetFill();
                    UIGraphics.RectFill(fullArea);

                    var logoArea = new CGRect(width * .35, statusFrame.Height, width * .3, navigationFrame.Height);
                    logo.Draw(logoArea);
                    var backgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

                    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

                    (renderer as ShellSectionRenderer).NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, UIBarMetrics.Default);

                    backgroundImage.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        return renderer;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Any thoughts?  Right now, the problem is that when it renders, there is an 800x200 image trying to squeeze into... 140x30 or so space on some emulators...

Thank you!

[image: Blurry Header Image]

Comment: it would help a lot if you provided some screenshots that illustrate the problem

Comment: I did just now -- it looks far worse on the actual phone.

Comment: have you tried creating @2x/@3x images for different screen densities?  And if you search on "UIImage resize blurry" you'll get quite a few hits

Comment: I'm using the embedded resources, so it's not quite the same as a @@2x, @@3x.  I've looked at the other "UIImage resize blurry" but they haven't been particularly helpful.  Some are in non-C#, so a little more difficult to understand (and the API appears to have changed)

Comment: I'd suggest trying the different density images in iOS instead of a single large image in your common project to see if it helps

Comment: I don't think you need a renderer. You can custom the Shell.TitleView in each ContentPage to achieve the result.

Comment: The fix was to change the UIGraphics.BeginImageContext to:
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(fullArea.Size, false, 0);

This kept the image quality, regardless of screen density.